# Empty "Error while trying to run project" in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am now randomly getting the error message:

```
 Error while trying to run project:
```

Followed by no message whatsoever* when I try to run ANY console application in Visual Studio 2013. This started recently, it is intermittent but happens most of the time.

[image]

A colleague of mine started getting this error the same time as I did. This can't be a coincidence.

*Try googling for that one...which is why I'm posing here.

Comment: Could be AV or some software running on your office PC. Try running Sysiternals ProcMon and see if you can see any failures

Comment: +1 We have Sophos. So yeah, that is what I'm suspecting as well.